# error: Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘func’ prevents the constraint ‘(Show t0)’ from being solved

Tags: haskell

I am studying about Haskell. And i am trying to make a while loop that everytime it runs it makes the value 'a' 2 times smaller with flooring after that.

this works fine:

```
func a = 
    if a > 0 then 
      func (a/2)
    else 
      print (a)
```

Now adding floor function to it.

```
func a = 
    if a > 0 then 
        func (floor (a/2))
    else 
        print (a)
```

now running it

```
func 5
```

And there is an error:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘func’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 12 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: func 1
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = func 1
```

The two questions i have is:

question 1:Why is this error occuring?

question 2:And how can i fix it?

I am using "repl.it" haskell. I'll appreciate every helps :)!

Comment: Trouble is, `floor` turns a fractional type into an integer type. Perhaps you wanted `div` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the function `floor` returns an `Integral` type, while the `/` function (the fractional divide-by operator) returns a `Fractional` type.

So you need `a` to be of a type that is both `Integral` and `Fractional`, which I believe does not exist (other Haskellers: feel free to correct me on this).

One way to fix this is to let the `Integral` returned by `floor` free to become any type of number:

```
func a = 
    if a > 0 then 
        func $ fromIntegral (floor (a/2))
    else 
        print (a)
```

Either way, it is a good practice to specify the type of your functions. The signature below would make your error clearer if you had tried it before using `fromIntegral`:

```
func :: Double -> IO ()
```

Comment: This was exactly my conclusion - that the use of (/) and floor meant finding a type that was an instance of both Integral and Fractional.  The error message strongly implies that such a type does not exist!

Comment: ...or, if you don't mind restricting it to `Integral` types, ```if a > 0 then func (a `div` 2) else print a``` seems significantly briefer. Callers that wanted to pass a non-`Integral` type could add one call to `floor` up front, or you could define a `funcRealFrac = func . floor`.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Thanks! The problem is fixed. And I added in some specific type of the function :)

Comment: While there is no type in *base* that is both an instance of `Integral` and `Fractional`, there might be one supplied by a library or the user.  In general, "No such type satisfying these constraints" is not something that GHC or Haskell can talk about; see my answer for elaboration :)  Furthermore, even if an instance *does* exist, the error would still happen.

Comment: For those who are reading this now: @JustinL.'s answer correctly explains the error reason while mine does not. My answer provides only a way to understand part of the problem and a way to provide a fix.

Answer (score 3):

@Marcelo Zabani's answer is correct in getting the code to work, but the error message itself is actually because of a different cause: [defaulting rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4).

Let's look at what your original function's type would be if inferred by GHC:

```
func a = 
    if a > 0 then 
      func (a/2)
    else 
      print (a)
```

You use `/2` (which requires `Fractional`) and `print` (which requires `Show`), which means that GHC would infer that `func` has the type:

```
func :: (Fractional a, Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

This is a perfectly fine type.  But, when you want to actually *call* `func`, you have to pick a *specific type* to call it with.  You can't call `(Fractional a, Show a) => a -> IO ()`; you have to call `Double -> IO ()`, or `Float -> IO ()`, etc.  So, how does GHC know which one you "want" to call, when you do `func 5`?

This is where **defaulting** kicks in.  By default, Haskell tries out all of the possible candidate types:

1. Integer
2. Double

this list is hard-coded into GHC (and the Haskell language spec).  It tries them out, in order, and it defaults the type variable to the first one that would compile.

In this case, it'd try out `Integer`, see that it doesn't work, and then try out `Double`, and then see that it does work, and calls `func :: Double -> IO ()`.

Now, your second function:

```
func a = 
    if a > 0 then 
        func (floor (a/2))
    else 
        print (a)
```

Now, because you call `floor (a/2)`, `a` now is inferred to have a `RealFrac` instance.  And because you call `func` with the result, `a` is now inferred to have an `Integral` instance.  So, the inferred type signature is:

```
func :: (RealFrac a, Integral a, Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

This, too, is a perfectly fine type.  This is why *defining* the function was fine, and no errors happened.

But, what happens when you call `func 5`?

GHC again tries out all of the defaulting candidates in order.  Integer fails, Double fails, so...defaulting can't resolve the ambiguity, so you get a compile-time error.

Note that the error is **not** because there is no type that is an instance of all three typeclasses.  This can never cause an error in Haskell, because typeclasses are global.  This would create weird situations where instances being declared in modules for types that aren't being used will cause code to compile or not compile.  So, a value that fails if there are *no* instances of a given typeclass is not allowed or sound in Haskell.

So, **even if** there was an instance of all Integral, RealFrac, and Show that existed, you would *still get an error*.  Imagine there was a type `Foo` that had all three necessary instances.  *Even in this case*, there would still be an error, because `Foo` is not in the list of defaulting types that GHC tries out.

The problem is that GHC needs help to figure out what type you want, since its list of defaults is exhausted.

So, you can do something like:

```
func (5 :: Foo)
```

which will work, provided `Foo` has an instance of `RealFrac`, `Integral`, *and* `Show`.

The problem isn't that no instance exists --- the problem is that GHC doesn't know which one to pick.

In general, this is what "Ambiguous type ..." errors mean: **not** that no instances exist, but that GHC needs your help to pick which type you want to instantiate a function as, since GHC can't infer from type inference.

The actual fix to get your code to work comes from the fact that you probably wanted things to work with `Double` in the first place.  If you give `func` a type signature, then the error will turn into `No instance for Integral Double`, which is the "actual" fundamental issue with your code.